# gephi - r - bi-partite affiliation network for virus-bat host matrix data

Tags: r, gephi, bipartite

I am working on creating a bi-partite affiliation network for virus-bat host matrix data in Gephi version 0.9.1. The data were processed using R and the final results saved as a .csv spreadsheet.

For both data sets, I have the row names listed as the bat species or virus species and the column names as the site names. For each species and site name, a numeric value is stored with the presence (number other than 0 indicating the number present) or absence (0).

Is this a good way to format virus-host data for later import into Gephi?

I have imported both data sets into Gephi as nodes and I am not able to perform any analysis on the data.

Any suggestions that you can offer will be very helpful.

I want to thank you in advance.

Comment: A good start is [here](https://shawngraham.gitbooks.io/dh-workbook/content/docs/supporting%20materials/multimode-networks.txt.html)

Comment: @Yannis P.  Thank you for sharing the link.